# Cruz T301: Internet Kick-Off

Tags: internet

I have a Cruz Tablet (T301) that runs Android 2.2.1.  For the longest time, I've tried to fix this matter on my own, but now I've run out of options.

When I get on the internet, my tablet has an interesting favor towards Facebook: not surprising because it comes with an app/bookmark of Facebook by default.  I can browse Facebook and share as much as I please as well as talk to my friends to my heart's content.  However, if I step outside of Facebook for as short as a second, my tablet kicks me off the internet.

Various options I have embraced to fix this matter.  I've already turned off my Wi-Fi, waited for a minute or two, and turned it back on to browse: that didn't work.  I even restarted my tablet with the aid of my paper clip that keep handy for situations such as this: that didn't work either.  I even became so bold as to perform a factory reset: even then I'm still being kicked off the internet.

I only have one application that allows me to browse the internet on my tablet: Browser, which also came by default.  Is there anything else that I haven't tried yet that may aid me in this situation?  Is it the application, or the tablet itself?  Do I have a virus, and I'm just not aware of it?  If I do have a virus, how do I get it fixed?

Comment: You did a factory reset so I suspect it is the stock ROM. Have you looked into rooting your tablet and flashing a different ROM?

Comment: No, I have not considered rooting my tablet to flash a different ROM.  In fact, I don't even know what that is, let alone how to do it on my tablet.  How can I root my tablet to flash a different ROM?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than continue to add comments, I'll post this as an answer. Steps to follow to root your tablet and flash a custom rom:

1. [backup your device](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-phone-backup-unlock-root-t1420351)
2. [root your device](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2212568)
3. [backup personal data and settings, if any, with titanium backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) (you can skip since you did a factory reset)
4. [install clockwork mod recovery](http://trueandroid.com/how-to-install-custom-recovery-in-most-android-devices/)
5. [flash with Feyer's Resurrection ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2212568); seems to be the best supported; no reports of wifi problems; also make sure to read his tips on keeping the T301 working well.

Comment: The ROM Manager [ClockworkMod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&rdid=com.koushikdutta.rommanager) requires me to have Google Play, which I cannot add to my Cruz T301 because it is not under the list of [supported devices](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/6A5685B30113F7A1B86CA918AE317127EB63) [x](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131).

Comment: You can manually install it by putting it's apk file on an SD card and running the apk file. Been out for a week leaving again for a day. Google for clockworkmod apk should find it.