# Cruz T301: Where Can I Get New Apps?

Tags: applications

I carry a Cruz Tablet (T301) with Android 2.2.1.  A long time ago, when my tablet used to work remotely fine, I remember having a place to where I could obtain apps, just as long as I had internet.  After my factory reset, I haven't been able to find any apps on my tablet where I can download a market for apps.  Adding onto the fact [I keep getting kicked off the internet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113797/cruz-t301-internet-kick-off), there is very little I know that I can do.  Does anyone have any suggestions for application markets, if and when my internet is restored to normal?

Comment: To close-voters: OP is not asking for an app, so it doesn't fall into that category. If you really want to "vote it closed", please consider "duplicate of [What are the alternative Android app markets?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/216/16575)" instead :)

Answer (score 0):

When you flash with a new ROM as I posted [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113797/cruz-t301-internet-kick-off/113837#113837), you should have access to the Google play store for apps.

Comment: I cannot get Google Play because it is not under the list of [supported devices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131).

Comment: This does not matter. Support for the Play Store is built into the new ROM. Your device will actually be better than original - one of the benefits of using a custom ROM>

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to take a look at my list of [App Markets](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_markets): There's e.g. the free and open F-Droid with its own market app, and there's Aptoide, also with its own market app. And of course there's Amazon, and there are plenty more.

Of additional interest for you:

- [Android Markets: How safe are alternative sources?](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android_markets_safe_to_use)
- [How safe is it to use Aptoide?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/74618/16575)
- our [alternative-markets](/questions/tagged/alternative-markets) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/alternative-markets/info)
- [What are the alternative Android app markets?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216/16575)